# Use Local Function in Module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small script that loads two modules, one is always the same as it only contains utility functions. The other is not known until runtime, so I load it with `import_module` and I get all the functions I need from it with `getattr`.

My problem is that one of the functions from the first module needs to call a function from the second module, as in:

```
weird_mod_name.py

def f1(a):
    # do stuff
    return stuff
```

```
utils_mod.py

def f2(b):
    c = f1(b) # here is where the function from the 'weird_mod_name' is called
    # do stuff
    return stuff
```

```
main.py

from importlib import import_module
from utils_mod import *

# weird_mod_name is computed here
mod = import_module('weird_mod_name')
f1 = getattr(mod, 'f1')

f2('something')
```

Is there any way of achieving this? I know that I can pass `f1` to `f2` but I was wondering if there was a way of using `f1` from within the `utils_mod`.

EDIT: I have been requested to add more information as to why is it not possible to just craft the same import in `utils_mod` as in the main program.

The idea is that I can pass arguments to the main program and then I would craft the name of the module I need to import: `weird_mod_name`. Of course, there is a finite number of `weird_mod_name`s, and in principle, all the combinations are valid as I have written them beforehand and all contain some version of the function `f1`, but this function is different across all the possible modules.

The final aim is that I can have a 'template file' that can be filled by a coder or an external program obtaining a module that has some functions. Then I would be able to call my script specifying it that it should use the module I have just written.

I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: is this working fine

Comment: since i think you are not importing weird_mod_name.py in utils_mod.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a setup-function before using the utils_mod. This has the advantage, that utils_mod does not need to have knowledge about what it actually calls or where it comes from. Also, you could exchange the functions at runtime as often as needed:

```
#in utils_mod
def setup_funcs(func1)
    global f1
    f1 = func1

def f2(b):
    c = f1(b)
    ...

#in main.py
...
f1 = getattr(mod, 'f1')
setup_funcs(f1)
f2('something')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import `f1` so that `utils_mod.f2` can see it you have to add the following line in the beginning of `utils_mod.py`

```
from importlib import import_module
mod = import_module('weird_mod_name')
f1 = getattr(mod, 'f1')
```

Then it should work...

Comment: Sorry, but this would not be possible because 'weird_mod_name' is not known until runtime.

Comment: I see what you mean. I just edited my answer for it to work for such a situation...

Comment: But in this case, `weird_mod_name` also needs to be computed in `utils_mod.py`, and for that you need information which only the main script has (parameters passed by the user). Is that still possible?

Comment: It sounds like you need to separate out the code that generates the information `weird_mod_name` needs and put that in a separate file. Then import that file into both `utils_mod` and `main`....

Comment: I more or less understand what you mean, but, how do you 'send' information to `utils_mod` so that I can calculate the name of `weird_mod_name` there?

Comment: Too much is ambiguous here. You need to provide more information about the nature of weird_mod_name and why it is so difficult to import in utils_mod in the manner I have outlined above...

Comment: I have added more information, I hope that it helps clarifying what it is my intention with my question.